# How To Access Specific Rows in an Import-Csv Array?

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-5.0

I need to split a large file upload into many parallel processes and want to use a single CSV file as input.
Is it possible to access blocks of rows from an `Import-Csv` object, something like this:

```
$SODAData = Import-Csv $CSVPath -Delimiter "|" |
            Where $_.Rownum == 20,000..29,999 | 
            Foreach-Object { ... }
```

What is the syntax for such an extraction?
 I'm using Powershell 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import-Csv` imports the file as an array of objects, so you could do something like this (using the range operator):

```
$csv = Import-CSv $CSVPath -Delimiter '|'
$SOAData = $csv[20000..29999] | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

An alternative would be to use `Select-Object`:

```
$offset = 20000
$count  = 10000
$csv = Import-Csv $CSVPath -Delimiter '|'
$SODAData = $csv |
            Select-Object -Skip $offset -First $count |
            ForEach-Object { ... }
```

If you want to avoid reading the entire file into memory you can change the above to a single pipeline:

```
$offset = 20000
$count  = 10000
$SODAData = Import-Csv $CSVPath -Delimiter '|' |
            Select-Object -Skip $offset -First $count |
            ForEach-Object { ... }
```

Beware, though, that with this approach you need to read the file multiple times for processing multiple chunks of data.

Comment: @Barry Remember that indexes are zero-based, so row 2000 in excel is 1999 in the array. :-)

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly! Thx @Ansgar

Comment: Strangely, though, @Frode, the first row that was extracted from $csv[20..29] was  row 22? There was a header in the csv file...

Comment: That's correct. The header line becomes the names of the object properties when using `Import-Csv`, so index 20 is data row 21 or line 22.