# How does one remove the top 18 lines of a .csv report using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm running usage reports from Verizon, and they conveniently fill the top 18 rows of the exported .csv with useless junk in order to make sure writing scripts is that much more of a headache /s. I'm setting it up to text users when they've exceeded their monthly allotment of company provided data. One user hit 70 gigs of his 2 gig allotment this month, prompting the script. Not asking for help with that bit, I've got that taken care of. But this one bit is giving me a headache and I thought I'd turn to you beatiful bastards. To any of you who are interested, once the script is done it'll be shared on Spiceworks.

I'm looking for a one-liner, I know it's out there. Essentially I want to

```
import-csv -path $filepath (import only rows 18-260) | select (blah blah blah)
```

Hey all, found the answer on here. It is here:
[How To Access Specific Rows in an Import-Csv Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333380/how-to-access-specific-rows-in-an-import-csv-array)